How do I update Ruby in my Jekyll project so I can deploy it on Netlify?
Whenever I try to deploy my website on Netlify, it always fails on the Initializing stage. I tried reinstalling Ruby on my computer, reinstalling all my gems, and then pushing the updates to my Github repo, but I still get the error below. How do I update Ruby in my Jekyll project so I can deploy it on Netlify?
3:25:44 PM: Starting to install dependencies
3:25:45 PM: Python version set to 3.8
3:25:45 PM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
3:25:46 PM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
3:25:46 PM: Using Bundler version 2.5.10 from Gemfile.lock
3:25:58 PM: ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
3:25:58 PM:     There are no versions of bundler (= 2.5.10) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems
3:25:58 PM:     bundler requires Ruby version >= 3.0.0. The current ruby version is 2.7.2.137.
3:25:59 PM: Error installing Bundler
3:25:59 PM: Failing build: Failed to install dependencies
3:25:59 PM: Failed during stage 'Install dependencies': dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1


"How do I update Ruby" – it depends. What operating system are you running and how did you install Ruby in the first place? If in doubt, you can check the current installation via which ruby or gem env.

What Ruby version are you running on your local computer? You need to set the Netlify Ruby version to the same version.

Running Kubuntu and I installed Ruby via the command line. I am running the 3.0.2 version, though. Checking which ruby tells me I'm running it in /usr/bin/ruby.

I solved this by creating a .ruby-version file in my project root and specifying the ruby version.
In my .ruby-version file I placed this on the first line of my .ruby version file :
3.2.0

Then push the changes, the site was able to initialize and build successfully on Netlify after that.
